# Is there a way to install normal android applications on android wear via bluetooth?

Tags: bluetooth, adb, wear-os

I know that Bluetooth debugging in android wear allows us to install apps in phone whose android wear companion gets installed in the watch via bluetooth. But I want to install normal android apps without any wear component to android wear. I know how to do this via usb, but is there a way to do this using bluetooth? I tried connecting the PC and the watch via bluetooth but can't get the adb to list the watch.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to install a stand-alone Wear app directly to the watch, use Bluetooth debugging.  You need to have your Wear device paired with your phone and connected to the Android Wear app.  Then follow the instructions here - https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/bt-debugging.html

I don't know about using a PC as you mentioned above.  You should follow the instructions at the link I listed and be sure to use the handled you have paired with your Wear device.

Also - you mention installing "normal android apps without a wear component".  Wear apps required the following element in the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />
```

This indicates that it is android wear-compatible software.  However, there some normal Android features that will not work on a Wear device.  Even if your program does work, the UI probably will not be intuitive or even really work at all.  Recommend providing a Wear-specific app for Wear devices specifically aimed at taking advantage of the form factor.

Answer (score 0):

I think might be missing the point of AndroidWear(AW) - you are NOT supposed to run Android apps on the watch, but companion apps that are designed to work along side your regular App.  Bottom line, you shouldn't be trying to install an app on the watch in the first place (it is hard because it shouldn't be done).

The AndroidWear platform is specifically designed to limit what you can run on the watch.  The idea is that you should use the AndroidWear watch for notifications, and other "glanceable" items, and continue using the phone for more complex operations:

From docs:

> Wearable apps are relatively small in size and functionality compared
>   to handheld apps. They contain only what makes sense on the wearable,
>   which is usually a small subset of the corresponding handheld app. In
>   general, you should carry out operations on the handheld when possible
>   and send the results to the wearable.

I expect there is NOT an officially supported way to do what you are trying to do, since this is something that is not supported or suggested in the first place.